# Testing streams with mock(tail) in Flutter (clean architecture)

Tags: flutter, testing, stream, mocking, clean-architecture

all
Could You check below code and tell me what I'm doing wrong. I have no problems with testing `Future<void> ,Future<Models>` etc., but when it comes to test streams I get some issues and can't find any solution for it.

I'm using clean architecture and problem exists when I want to test "data repository implementation". While running test I get feedback that my "result" is `"Right(Instance of '_ControllerStream<List<ProductModel>>')"`. Below I am sending code, maybe You could find some fast solution.

Below some hints/code cuts according data source and repo implementation:

```
  Stream<List<ProductModel>> streamProducts({
    required String productCategory,
});

@override
  Future<Either<Failure, Stream<List<Product>>>> fetchProducts({required String productCategory}) async{
    try{
      final result =  productDataSource.streamProducts(productCategory: productCategory);
      return Right(result);
    }catch(error){
      return const Left(StreamProductFailure(failureMessage: 'Unable to stream products'));
    }
```

below test file:

```
class MockProductDataSource extends Mock implements ProductDataSource{}

void main() {

  late ProductDataSource dataSource;
  late ProductRepoImp repoImp;

  setUp((){
    dataSource = MockProductDataSource();
    repoImp = ProductRepoImp(productDataSource: dataSource);
  });



final product = ProductModel.empty();


group('stream product', () {

    test('should call stream product from data source and finish successfully', () async {
      //Arrange
      when(()=> dataSource.streamProducts(productCategory: any(named:'productCategory'))).thenAnswer((_) => Stream.value([product]));
      //Act
      final result = await repoImp.fetchProducts(productCategory: product.productCategory);
      //Assert
      expect(result, equals(Right([product])));

    });

  });
```